# How to display list of images with some images double-width

Tags: listview, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to achieve this on my Xamarin project

[image]

So what I want is to display my images from my `Category` entity like this, some would expand horizontally and some would be displayed by two in one row.

What I have achieved so far is this.

[image]

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppCrijoya.Views.CategoryPage">
    <ContentPage.Content>

        <StackLayout>

            <ListView x:Name="listTemp" HasUnevenRows="True" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="False" ItemTapped="ListViewCategorias_ItemTapped" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="Start" HeightRequest="270" RowSpacing="6">
                                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Aspect="Fill" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"></Image>
                            </Grid>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>

        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>

    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Text="CERRAR SESIÓN" Clicked="Logout_Clicked"/>
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    
</ContentPage>
```

Please help, I'm new to Xamarin and I'm still trying to understand how the views work.

Comment: What is wrong with what you have?  Have you tried the different options for the `Aspect` property?

Comment: @Jason I want some Images to be smaller as my example. I have tried already all the aspect properties but can't achieve what I want. I don't know if there is a way of making an if statement on the xamls file and set certain height and width depending on the image

Comment: do some rows have 2 cells and some rows have just one?  This is not something you can easily do with a ListView

Comment: @Jason Exactly, some have 2 cells and some just one. And I get the images from the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply use [Grid](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid) to achieve this layout.If you want some Images to be smaller,you could set `Margin="10,3,3,3"` property for the image.

Below is the code snippet for your reference:

```
  <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" ></RowDefinition>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image  Margin="10,10,10,6" Background="aqua" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Aspect="AspectFit" Source="XamarinLogo.png"></Image>
        <Image Margin="10,3" Background="aqua" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="XamarinLogo.png"></Image>

        <Image  Margin="10,3,3,3"   Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71sNNCTfMuL._FMwebp__.jpg"></Image>
        <Image Margin="0,3,3,3" Grid.Row="2"  Grid.Column="1" Aspect="AspectFill" Source="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71sNNCTfMuL._FMwebp__.jpg"></Image>

        <Image Margin="10,3,3,3" Background="green" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Source="XamarinLogo.png"></Image>
        <Image Margin="0,3,3,3"  Background="green" Grid.Row="3"  Grid.Column="1" Source="XamarinLogo.png"></Image>

        <Image Margin="10,3,3,6" Background="black" Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Source="XamarinLogo.png"></Image>
        <Image Margin="0,3,3,6" Background="black" Grid.Row="4"  Grid.Column="1" Source="XamarinLogo.png"></Image>

    </Grid>
```

MS official reference link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/grid

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/margin-and-padding

[image]

Comment: This won't work for me as I am working with my images from my database

Comment: You can use binding to the image source which saved in database.And don't forget to set margin property that will work.